# How does this program execute?

Tags: c, recursion, static

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    static int i = 5; 
    if(--i){ 
        main(); 
        printf("%d ",i); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of above code is 0 0 0 0. I get why it is 0 in the first place, but why is 0 printed three more times?

Comment: Because there is only one `i`.It can't be `0`, and `1`, and `2`, ... at the same time. And when the recursed `main()`s return, `i` is printed again.

Comment: @pmg I get that, also specified in the question. I don't get why the code executes to print 0 three more times. Like after the first 0 is printed, how does the flow of execution go back to the beginning of program, instead of returning 0.

Comment: Just a little FYI: the `#include <stdlib.h>` is not needed for this example.

Comment: @pmg it was in the code question so I copied it anyways FYI

Comment: Imagine that on the very first time in the `if` you don't call `main()` but instead call `main4()` (`i` is 4, `main4()` is identical to your `main()`). ... then, in `main4()` you call `main3()` and so on till at the end you call `main1()` which prints `0` and returns. **where does `main1()` return to?** Yep! To `main2()` which prints 0 and returns to `main3()` ... all the way back to the very first `main()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the `static` variable is shared between all calls to `main`. Then consider the code as it is executed recursively:

```
int main() {
    static int i = 5; // 5
    if (--i) { // 4
        main() {
            if (--i) { // 3
                main() {
                    if (--i) { // 2
                        main() {
                            if (--i) { // 1
                                 main() {
                                     if (--i) // 0 (false)
                                     return 0;
                                 }
                                 printf("%d ",i); // 0
                            }
                            return 0;
                        }
                        printf("%d ",i); // 0
                    }
                    return 0;
                }
                printf("%d ",i); // 0
            }
            return 0;
        }
        printf("%d ",i); // 0
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for enlightening the vision with flow of execution!

Answer (score 1):

The crux is that since `i` is `static`, everything sets the same `i` variable. And `main` calls itself recursively until `i` is a falsy-value.

```
int main() 
{ 
  static int i = 5; 
  if(--i){ // i is now 4
    main(); 
      { 
        if(--i){ // i is now 3
          main(); 
            { 
              if(--i){ // i is now 2
                main(); 
                  { 
                    if(--i){ // i is now 1
                     main(); 
                        { 
                          if(--i){ // i is now 0, which is false, so main isn't called
                          }
                        }
                      printf("%d ",i); //print "0"
                   }
                 }
                printf("%d ",i);  //print "0"
             }
           }
          printf("%d ",i);  //print "0"
        }
      }
    printf("%d ",i);  //print "0"
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for enlightening the vision with flow of execution!

Answer (score 0):

Variable `i` is static. So the variable get value at the first time the program reaches line 5 and line 5 never execute anymore. and since variable `i` is static, every time that `main` got executed, it accesses the same `i` that it had accessed before. and if any function call changes the value of `i`, its values in other function calls will change. so while the value of `i` is not `0` the main function got called and when its value becomes equal to `0`, main function returns and `printf()`s start to executing and printing `i`, which is `0`

Answer (score 0):

It goes like this

```
static int i = 5
if (--i) //i == 4{
  if (--i) //i == 3{
    if(--i) // i ==2{ 
      if (--i) // i==1{
        if (--i) //i==0 this means i==false{
        }
        print (i) //i ==0
      }
      print(i) //i ==0
    }
    print(i) //i==0
  }
  print(i) //i==0
return 0
```

This is what happens when you execute that code,
4 recursive calls, once a call ends it print the variable i which is static so it's literally the same one for all the calls.

Why 4 prints and not 5?

Because the -- used as prefix works like this

```
i = i-1
if (i)
```

while the -- used as postfix works like this

```
if (i)
i = i-1
```

Comment: It's okay, I got it!  Thanks for enlightening the vision with flow of execution!

Answer (score 0):

as i is declared `static`, it will be on `data segment`(if you remove static it will be on stack and will have different values in each stack frame but here i=5 initialized at start everytime if you remove `static` your program will get into infinite function call loop, as `i` will never become zero so recursion will not terminate)

and as  `i` is `static` whatever the change you make will be retained throught the function calls.
when `i` reaches to zero recurssion ends as `if(0)` becomes false, when it ruturns, when it return it will print final value of i i.e zero